# Pandas slice fails with list of DatetimeIndex labels

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, slice

I have a 12x3 dataframe storing 2017 monthly average, max, and min temperatures:

```
import pandas as pd

tavg = pd.Series([55.8, 57.2, 61.0, 63.6, 63.3, 66.7, 71.7, 72.0, 71.5, 71.5, 65.6, 61.4])
tmax = pd.Series([62.7, 62.6, 69.3, 71.9, 69.4, 72.6, 77.5, 77.3, 78.5, 80.4, 73.7, 72.4])
tmin = pd.Series([48.8, 51.8, 52.8, 55.4, 57.1, 60.9, 65.8, 66.8, 64.6, 62.5, 57.3, 50.3])

temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
temp_df['TAVG'] = tavg
temp_df['TMIN'] = tmin
temp_df['TMAX'] = tmax

dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-01', freq='MS')

temp_df.index = dates
```

I'd like to slice by label a list of dates, for instance 2017-01-01 and 2017-05-01.

Slicing each of these dates individually works fine:

```
temp_df.loc['2017-01-01']

TAVG    55.8
TMIN    48.8
TMAX    62.7
Name: 2017-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64

temp_df.loc['2017-05-01']

TAVG    63.3
TMIN    57.1
TMAX    69.4
Name: 2017-05-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

But slicing with a list of these dates raises a KeyError:

```
temp_df.loc[['2017-01-01', '2017-05-01']]

"KeyError: "None of [['2017-01-01', '2017-05-01']] are in the [index]"
```

Is there a special trick to slicing with a list of index labels when working with a DatetimeIndex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing fails because the index are of type `Timestamp`. The code `temp_df.loc[['2017-01-01', '2017-05-01']]` looks for String labels. Use the below code to parse them as `Timestamp`.

```
temp_df.loc[[pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2017-05-01')]]
```

Output:

```
            TAVG    TMIN    TMAX
2017-01-01  55.8    48.8    62.7
2017-05-01  63.3    57.1    69.4
```

For your code to work you need to change the index type to `str`

```
temp_df.index = temp_df.index.astype(str)
temp_df.loc[['2017-01-01', '2017-05-01']]
```

Output:

```
            TAVG    TMIN    TMAX
2017-01-01  55.8    48.8    62.7
2017-05-01  63.3    57.1    69.4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a range of dates, just
 the two dates of 2017-01-01 and 2017-05-01. Why is slicing with a list of labels failing in my case?